# Efficientley counting occurrences of each character in a file - scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, I want the fastest way to get a map of count of occurrences for each character in a text file, how can I do that?(I used groupBy but I believe it is too slow)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your effort?

Answer (score 2):

I think that `groupBy()` is probably pretty efficient, but it simply collects the elements, which means that counting them requires a 2nd traversal.

To count all `Char`s in a single traversal you'd probably need something like this.

```
val tally = Array.ofDim[Long](127)
io.Source.fromFile("someFile.txt").foreach(tally(_) += 1)
```

`Array` was used for its fast indexing. The index is the character that was counted.

```
tally('e')  //res0: Long = 74
tally('x')  //res1: Long = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't a map be faster than array?

Comment: I don't think so. According to the collections [performance characteristics page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html), indexing (`apply()` method) on an `Array` is constant time, while indexing (lookup) on a `Map` is effective constant time. Probably little, or no, difference, but to increment an `Array` value requires indexing twice `m(x)=m(x)+1`. (But double indexing might also be hidden behind the `+=1` operation on an `Array`. I'm not sure.)

Comment: Though I do have a problem with the array, it is restricted to 127 characters only.. if my file will be multi language? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use a bigger `Array` or use a `Map`. One _might_ be slightly faster, the other, more memory efficient.

Comment: HashMap  seems to be very slow when the files are 100mb+ (about 2 minutes !!) What is the most efficient map?(for inserting and retreiving)

Comment: I don't know. You should run some tests to find out just how much the `Map` operations are costing you. How much faster is it if you get the count of only one character? (i.e. no `Map` operations.) How big does the `Map` get? A `Map` with thousands of keys will run slower than a `Map` with 100 keys. Are you using `withDefaultValue()` on your `Map`? Is it faster without it? Is it faster if you use `Array` instead of `Map`?

Comment: Using array takes about 4 seconds for the same file that will take 2 minutes using map.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Read the file first:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("/Users/Al/.bash_profile").getLines.toSeq
```

You can then write a method that takes the List of lines read and counts the occurence for a given character:

```
  def getCharCount(c: Char, lines: Seq[String]) = {
    lines.foldLeft(0){(acc, elem) =>
      elem.toSeq.count(_ == c) + acc
    }
  }
```